# Buscar datos duplicados PHP y MYSQL usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

alguien puede ayudarme, quiero hacer un insert y update pero para eso necesito verificar si no existe un e-mail y celular con los mismos datos.

function inserir(DadosPacientes $pacientes) {

```
    try {            
        $conecta = $this->conectar(); 
        $conecta->beginTransaction();
        if($consulta->busca("SELECT * FROM"))


        $sql = "INSERT INTO pacientes(nome,dtnasc,endereco,email,celular) VALUES(:nome,:dtnasc,:endereco,:email,:celular)";
        $statement = $conecta->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindvalue(":nome", $pacientes->getNome());
        $statement->bindvalue(":dtnasc", $pacientes->getDtNasc());
        $statement->bindvalue(":endereco", $pacientes->getEndereco());
        $statement->bindvalue(":email", $pacientes->getEmail());
        $statement->bindvalue(":celular", $pacientes->getCelular());
        $execute = $statement->execute();

        $conecta->commit();
        if($execute == true){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            throw new PDOException($execute);
        }



    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        if ((isset($conecta)) && ($conecta->inTransaction())) {//comprova se uma existe e se  está ativa
            $conecta->rollBack();  //desfaz uma transação 
        }
        print($exc->getMessage()); //obtema mensagem de excução
        return FALSE;
    } finally {
        if (isset($conecta)) {
            unset($conecta);
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es el insert sin el select para validar los datos, si alguien tiene alguna idea de como podria hacer para validar si email y celular ya existen. Desde ya muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiero primero hacer un SELECT buscando dichos campos, si ya existen, realizar UPDATE, si no hacer un INSERT.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: @Aprendiz ¿Qué hay de malo con esta respuesta?, no sé si es correcta pero es una respuesta aun si no es correcta.

Comment: @eyllanesc, gracias por tu comentario!!!, Saludos...